# Numpy is not working on pypy3.8: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'numpy.core._multiarray_umath'

Tags: python, numpy

I'm trying to use pypy3.8 to improve the speed of my code.

However, numpy module is not working.

`ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'numpy.core._multiarray_umath'` was occurred

I copied numpy from the python 3.9.3 library folder and pasted it into the pypy3 folder.

Also, I checked it was installed by `pypy3 -m pip install numpy` and the result was `Requirement already satisfied: numpy in c:\users\username\desktop\pypy3\lib\site-packages (1.21.4)`

What should I do to resolve this error??

Should I use python 3.8 to solve this problem?

Comment: Well, I'd suggest that you show your code, as a start.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I just imported numpy and the code was ```a = np.array([1, 2, 3])```